# Moebius transformation in upper half plane model

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I am studying Hyperbolic Geometry on my own. More especially, I am studying the Moebius transformation of the upper half plane model in hyperbolic geometry. But I got stuck studying it. I am looking for a solution of this problem. The problem is as follows:

Find the Moebius transformation  that rotates the hyperbolic plane about $i$ through an angle of $\frac { \pi}{4}$.

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: Do you know an isometry from the upper half-plane model to the disk model?  Conjugate a rotation of the disk by this isometry.

Comment: The stabilizer of $i$ is (the image in the group of Möbius transformations of) $SO_2(\Bbb{R})$ and the derivative of $f(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d),ad-bc=1$ is $1/(cz+d)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The stabilizer of $i$ in the upper half-plane consists of elliptic linear-fractional transformations $g_A(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ corresponding to matrices
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\
-\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
\end{array}\right]
$$
(which makes it easy to remember: Euclidean rotations correspond to hyperbolic rotations). The angle of rotation $\phi$ of the matrix $A$ acting on ${\mathbb R}^2$ correspond to the angle of rotation $2\phi$ for the Moebius transformation $g_A$. (This is again easy to remember since for $A=-I$, rotation by $\pi$, $g_A=id_{\mathbb H^2}$, rotation by $2\pi$.)
The rest you can figure out on your own.